# How to add or concatenate money type and string on query mssql

Tags: sql-server, concatenation, addition

I have a situation like this

I got a column with 'money' type, 2 decimal . Example data:(65.00)

I need to add 12 zero / 000000000000 to it so that the output would be like this:

> (65.00 convert to 6500) + (000000000000) = 000000006500

Output: 000000006500

How can I achieve this?. Thank you for your help and suggestion

Comment: You have better chances of getting an answer if you tag the question with the **language** you are using. `concatenation` and `add` are useless tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a couple of casts, multiplying by 100, and using REPLICATE('0') to pad with the requisite number of zeroes).
I'm assuming you DO want up to 2 x trailing decimals, but no more.

```
DECLARE @value MONEY;
SET @value = 65.123;

DECLARE @intValue BIGINT;
SET @intValue = CAST(@value * 100.0 AS BIGINT);
SELECT REPLICATE('0',12-LEN(@intValue)) + CAST(@intValue AS NVARCHAR(20));
```

Returns `000000006512`

If you need to do this on a set, a CTE can be used for the intermediate step, e.g.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT CAST(MoneyField * 100.0 AS BIGINT) AS intValue
    FROM SomeTable
)
SELECT
    REPLICATE('0',12-LEN(cte.intValue)) + CAST(cte.intValue AS NVARCHAR(20))
    FROM cte;
```

[Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6669b/1)

Comment: thank you StuartLC. I'm about to change the tag. Thanks again for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is Possible .But output Column should be in the type of varchar(15) .If you want to do further operation of your output you have to convert that into int or whatever

```
SELECT CONCAT(REPEAT('0',12-LENGTH(65.00)),(65.00*100));
```